# Is there a way to implement Smolin's variant of Shor's algorithm?

Tags: q#

I'm currently investigating Shor's algorithm and especially Smolin's variant, that he described in his article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7007

My applied changes according to Smolin's variant are here:
https://github.com/Sage-Cat/quantum_shors_algorithm

The paper I read you can find in repository `docs/Smolin_pretending_large_numbers.pdf`.

To be concise, he suggests to make this changes:

1. Find `a`, such as `a^2 = 1 mod N`, using Extended Euclidean Algorithm
2. Set period `r = 2`
3. And somehow use 2 qubits to simulate finding `a` and `r` or smth. (I don't understand the actual use of 2 qubits). From his paper I got only that he uses 2 qubits to get specific CNOT entanglement like this:

```cs
    operation ValidateAUsingQuantumSubroutine(a : Int, N : Int, r : Int) : Result {
        use qubits = Qubit[2];
        // Prepare qubits
        H(qubits[0]);
        CNOT(qubits[0], qubits[1]);

        // Measurement could be used to validate assumptions or effects
        let measurement = M(qubits[0]);

        ResetAll(qubits);
        return measurement;
    }
```

But how it helps to validate a, I don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing to understand is that the quadratic residue $a$, that Smolin is getting you to compute, is exactly the same $a$ that Shor's algorithm is finding by using period-finding against a random base $g$. When you set $g=a$, you get a vacuous execution of Shor's algorithm where it computes that this $g$'s period is 2, and returns $g^{2/2} = \text{...drumroll...} = a$ as the quadratic residue to use for factoring.

So the first cheat is knowing the value you're trying to find. The second cheat is using the fact that you *know* the period of $f(x) = g^x$ is 2, and therefore Shor's algorithm will still work if you substitute this complicated $f$ with some trivial period-2 function like bit-flipping. So you do that. And also you reduce your phase estimation register size from $2n$ to 1, since that's sufficient for period 2. Thus the whole quantum part degenerates into a CNOT gate conjugated by Hadamard gates on its control.

These cheats are cheating. But that was the intent of the paper. It's a reaction to papers that claim to factor numbers with quantum computers by using subtler cheats.

Comment: So Smolin is simply saying that there is no real use for such "oversimplified" algorithms, except for educational purposes? And that such "simplifications" speedup nothing?

Comment: @SageCat Yes, that they speedup nothing of importance.